# Cannot Ping Or Remote Desktop into Hyper-V PC Via IP Address On Host

Tags: ip, ping, remote-desktop, hyper-v, netstat

I have a bit of a bizarre problem. I have a Hyper-V VM and I cannot connect to it via IP address on the host computer.

I intend to use it as an SQL server to host a database for a website while I test it, and the first step I can see in this endeavour is to make sure the IP addresses work externally.

Other PCs on the LAN appear to be able to connect just fine via the IP address on Remote Desktop. I cannot do so. I also cannot connect through SQL Management Studio (named pipes or TCP/IP). Although named pipes gives an error relating to being denied access as opposed to IPs which are just not found.

I have tried pinging both ways:

VM => Host : Always gives a "Destination Host Unreachable" error

Host => VM: Always gives a "Request Timed Out" error

As for netstat -a -n, I can see that the VM is listening to 3389 (default Hyper V port, which makes sense).

Regarding Firewalls, all have been turned off on all machines. I can tell that the firewall is not the issue.

If you need any more information to help me to diagnose and treat the problem, please ask me as I would like to get this sorted as quickly as possible.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which windows server version do you use?
Windows Server 2016 blocks insecure RDP connections (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4295591/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-when-to-rdp-to-azure-vm).

Since RDP uses CredSSP you have to install the current Windows Patches.

Do you can ping the DNS server by IP address from your VM?
Is ICMP (ICMP = the thing you need for ping) on your host enabled?

Here is a Checklist for ICMP:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc749323(v=ws.10)

Comment: We are currently using Windows Server 2012 R2.

I'll check the ICMP and get back to you. EDIT: Enabled both ICMPv4 and v6 and it still times out.

Comment: can you ping the DNS server by IP?

Comment: The DNS (Domain Controller) appears to make no difference. Others on the network can connect. Just not the host that is running the Hyper V session.

Comment: that's odd. I had problems like this where the solution was to remove the switch and NIC from the VM and add them back again. Hyper-V is there really strange

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

Just switched to another physical computer and it was fine.